# How to search within specific files in VS Code?

Tags: regex, file, search, visual-studio-code, find

There are several hundred files in the workspace and I would like to perform a search within specific files. For example,

Find `"Hello world"` in the files starting with these three letters `"mkr*"`

Is there a way to accomplish this kind of search in the VS Code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open search (Mac: <kbd>command+shift+f</kbd>, Windows/Linux: <kbd>ctrl+shift+f</kbd>).
2. Toggle search details (Mac: <kbd>command+shift+j</kbd>, Windows/Linux: <kbd>ctrl+shift+j</kbd>).
3. In the "search" input, enter the keywords. In this case, `Hello world`.
4. In the "files to include" input, add the pattern. In this case, `*/mkr*.*`.

Comment: Took me a while to activate the "files to include" box. Turns out I had to click on the `...` button first show this box. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Yeah, that's actually the icon for toggling the search details (step 2 in my answer, if you prefer keyboard shortcuts).

Answer (score 2):

Click '...' and it will shows **file to include** and **files to exclude**.

[image]